# C# If statement calling a method not working?

Tags: c#

Here is the code:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        List<string> smallList = new List<string>(new string[]{
            " ", 
            " "});

        List<List<string>> bigList = new List<List<string>>(new List<string>[]{
            smallList, 
            getSmallList()});

        if (bigList[0][0] == " ") 
        {
        }

        if (bigList[0] == smallList)
        {
        }

        if (bigList[1] == smallList)
        {
        }

        if (bigList[1] == getSmallList()) 
        {
        }
    }

    public static List<string> getSmallList()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>(new string[]{
            " ", 
            " "});

        return list;
    }
```

The first and second 'if' statements work.  These make sense.  The third and fourth 'if' statements do not work.  Can you help me understand why not?

Comment: You have to be more specific about how they "do not work". What is the behavior you expect, and what is the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: Define "do not work".

Comment: You keep making new `List<string>` objects.  Two different objects are not the same object, so `==` is false.

Comment: You have to more specific to let us understand your problem please [Visit](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: By "do not work", I mean that the 'if' statement does not read true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (bigList[0][0] == " ")
```

This is **true** because the value of `bigList[0][0]` is also `" "`, and the strings are compared by their value.  Since they have the same value, the comparison is true.

```
if (bigList[0] == smallList)
```

This is **true** because `bigList[0]` points to the same object in memory as `smallList` does.  They are two references to the same thing.  Since they are compared by reference, the references are equal.

```
if (bigList[1] == smallList)
```

This is **false** because `bigList[1]` *does not* point to the same object in memory as `smallList` does.  The objects were created the same way, but they are *different* objects.  (Much in the same way that two identical cars are still different cars.)  They are compared by reference, and the references are to different instances in memory.

```
if (bigList[1] == getSmallList())
```

This is **false** for the same reason as the previous one.  Only in this case it's more clear because `getSmallList()` is immediately and explicitly create a new instance of an object in memory.  To continue the analogy, another identical car *just rolled off* the assembly line.  It looks the same, but it's a different car.

Objects are by default compared for equality by reference (unless you override that functionality in the class definition, or provide custom comparison logic).  Any two instances of an object, no matter how *intuitively similar* they may appear, are two separate instances.

Comment: Thanks David, you and Roma got it.